# Can tree traversal "print code" return instead?

Tags: python, data-structures, nodes, recursive-datastructures

Since i have always seen tree traversal codes printing the data inside the tree. i started wondering is it possible to create a function where it RETURNS me the data, instead of printing it. 
I tried to implement my thoughts as i tried to manipulate the print "Custom made" function by changing print into return. however since there was recursion things got messy and it did not work as I wanted.
So I tried making a self.list=[] and then append into it every single node and its data. it did not work also using the recursion.

this is the Code i tried:

```
    class BinaryTree():
        def __init__(self, item,value):

            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.item = item
            self.value = value

            self.list=[]

        def insert(self, item,value):
            if self.value:
                if value < self.value:
                    if self.left is None:
                        self.left = BinaryTree(item,value)
                    else:
                        self.left.insert(item,value)


                elif value > self.value:
                    if self.right is None:
                        self.right = BinaryTree(item,value)
                    else:

                        self.right.insert(item,value)

                elif value == self.value:
                    if self.left is None:
                        self.left = BinaryTree(item,value)
                    else:
                        self.left.insert(item,value)
            else:
                self.item=item
                self.value=value


        def PrintTree(self):

            if self.right:
                self.right.PrintTree()
            print(["item : " + self.item, "value : " + self.value]),

            if self.left:
                self.left.PrintTree()


        #Custom made functions

        def print(self):
            if self.right:
                self.right.print()
            new = {self.item,self.value}
            self.list.append(new)
            print(self.list)
            if self.left:
                self.left.print() 


Root = BinaryTree('car', 18 )
Root.insert('truck',23)
Root.insert('airplane',99)
Root.insert('bus',17)

Root.print() # during recursion gives me everything, however the items are not saved permanently in self.list
print("\n")
print(Root.list) # should give me everything, but gives me only root.
```

It should append all into list and not replace them. will appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a list you can `yield from` the recursion. This makes everything very easy to read and understand. In the end just wrap that in a `list()` if you want a list rather than a generator:

```
     def traverse(self):
            if self.right:
                yield from self.right.traverse()
            yield (self.item, self.value)
            if self.left:
                yield from self.left.traverse()


Root = BinaryTree('car', 18 )
Root.insert('truck',23)
Root.insert('airplane',99)
Root.insert('bus',17)

list(Root.traverse())
# [('airplane', 99), ('truck', 23), ('car', 18), ('bus', 17)]
```

If you want to return a list directly from the method, obviously you can wrap this and return a list.